# Does Termux call fork/exec system calls in Android?

Tags: linux, termux

There are tutorials (e.g., [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VJJobXiVewY) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FBRYZr85rbE)) that use Termux to compile and run cpp codes in Android. Does Termux run fork/exec system calls and start running the program's main function? More generally, do terminal emulators in android really create Linux processes running directly on the hardware or do they act as a virtual machine and introduce a performance loss?

Comment: Termux is a terminal emulator and it runs a shell (`bash` by default). You run commands there like any other shell on some Linux PC. System calls work  as on any Linux system (except those which require elevated privileges or those filtered through `seccomp`). Yes terminal emulators create native Linux processes when an executable is run. Virtual machines are run only for Java apps installed as `.apk`s which have `.dex` bytecode to be run by Java-like VMs.